# массив в python

Tags: java, python

```
complex[i] = new Complex(audio[(times*Harvester.CHUNK_SIZE)+i], 0);
```

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код который написан на Яве, тот же код мне нужен в python.Только не знаю куда надо 0 дописать.

```
complex[i] = audio[(times*np.size(CHUNK))+i]
```

Comment: `complex[i] = complex(audio[(times*np.size(CHUNK))+i], 0)` ? Кст, в питоне `complex` -- это встроенная функция, поэтому не называйте ее именем переменные. Функция complex: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#complex

Comment: Ya ne znal pro eto.Spasibo bolshoye.

Comment: вы проверили мой вариант с `complex(...)`?

Comment: Da, vse rabotayet spasibo esho raz .

Answer (score 1):

Используйте встроенную функцию [complex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#complex) и лучше переименуйте переменную с массивом `complex[]`, т.к. это соответствует названию функции [complex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#complex) и после присваивания в переменную `complex` она (переменная) будет вызываться вместо **функции** `complex`, что приведет к странным ситуациям.

Пример:

```
complex_items[i] = complex(audio[(times*np.size(CHUNK))+i], 0)
```

Comment: Spasibo bolshoye

Comment: @John, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)